# How to properly get related resources in Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm currently trying to design an API using Tastypie but as soon as I'm dealing with related models and resources, I'm stuck with design questions like "should I use `full=true`? Why ?. 
Don't worry if the post is long, it's just because I try to explain things :)

Let's take a simple example with 3 related resources:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class meta():
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
        # Some other required fields

class ClientUserResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user') # I could add full=True

    class meta():
        queryset = ClientUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client_users'
        # Some other required fields

class CardResource(ModelResource):
    linked_client = fields.ForeignKey(ClientResource, 'linked_client') # I could add full=True

    class meta():
        queryset = Card.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'cards'
        # Some other required fields
```

There is no problem to make simple GET requests to get information with this 3 related resources.
But now, imagine that each resource has custom Authorization, Validation, and maybe other overriden methods like `obj_get_list()` or `dehydrate()`.

If I want to have information of a card and its user (we assume the data we need is spread over the 3 resources), let's describe different solutions that we have:

**Solution A -> 1 request, using `full=True` in FK fields**

GET request on `"http://myapp/api/v1/cards/42"` will give me all the informations that I need.
Nevertheless, in this case, custom Authorization method of UserResource and ClientUserResource will never be called. This means API users will access to information they should not access. Of course I could manage this in the Authorization method of CardResource, but it is really a bad thing (not DRY, not its role to do it)

**Solution B -> 3 requests for 3 'nesting' levels, `full=False` in FK fields**

- GET request on `"http://myapp/api/v1/cards/42"` provide me the uri of
  linked ClientUserResource.
- GET request on *the URI of ClientUserResource* provide me the uri of linked UserResource
- GET request on *the URI of UserResource* provide me the data I need on my
  UserResource

I can see 2 problems with solution B:

- Performance: if my model is more complex, I need to perform lots of requests
- Security : even if it's not as terrible as the solution 1, when you make a GET request on a list, when the answer is an empty list, or a list containing uris (uris contains ids), it's already a pice of information.

What solution would you use in this case? Can you see a better way to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure `"custom Authorization method of UserResource and ClientUserResource will never be called"`?

Each resource has its own authentication, authorization, and validation and tastypie will immediately returns error when error occur.

No problem if you `full=True` all the foreign keys or many to many keys as long as not REVERSE RELATION. Of course, this way your result may be very-very complex.

If you want to restrict user to not receive some confidential fields, you can do it in [dehydrate](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#the-dehydrate-cycle) or [full_dehydrate](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#full-dehydrate) function.

Comment: Are you saying that the custom Authorization should work? From the very beginning, if `BResource` is related to `AResource`, when getting `AResource` with `full=true` on the `BResource` field, no rule of `BResource` is checked (authorization, validation, and even allowed_methods). That's why I think I can't have a "clean" API putting `full=true`on related fields.

Comment: I posted another question related to this one (but quite different) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909483/why-does-full-true-breaks-resources-behaviour-in-django-tastypie
Thanks for your help.